# "Status" field on Item Fulfillment Form

Tags: netsuite

There is a field called "status" on the Item Fulfillment if you are using Pick/Pack/Ship feature. The field id is shipstatus and it's values are Picked, Packed, and Shipped.

I cannot find this field on the form to move it's place at all. I have looked under ship status and just status. I have expanded all the subtabs to use ctrl+f to search for it. I cannot find it.

Has anyone else hit this? Am I missing something? How can I move the location of this field?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Status Field]

This field is under the "Classification" tab on the main screen of my Item Fulfillment transactions.

If you want to move the field, you can either create custom record based on the standard Item Fulfillments and move the field to the required ta or you could edit the original form(I believe this is still possible).

Comment: It shows on the form but not when you try to customize it. NetSuite eventually responded to my case stating this is an enhancement

Comment: So is the enhancement that you cannot change this field?

Comment: Netsuite views having the ability to move this field on the form (and all other abilities you have when it shows on that page) as an enhancement. Frankly it seems like a defect when they added that but oh well